# What is wrong with my normalized orthographic coordinates in openGL?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to create a triangle in openGL that won't stretch when I resize the window. I pass this orthographic matrix to my vertex shader.

```
void resize(int w, int h) {
float orthMat[4][4];

orthMat[0][0] = 2.0/w;
orthMat[1][1] = -2.0/h;
orthMat[3][3] = 1.0;

orthMat[3][3] = 1.0;
orthMat[3][0] = -1.0;
orthMat[3][1] = -1.0;

orthMat[0][1] = 0.0;
orthMat[0][2] = 0.0;
orthMat[0][3] = 0.0;
orthMat[1][0] = 0.0;
orthMat[1][3] = 0.0;
orthMat[1][2] = 0.0;
orthMat[2][0] = 0.0;
orthMat[2][1] = 0.0;
orthMat[2][2] = 0.0;
orthMat[2][3] = 0.0;
orthMat[3][2] = 0.0;

glUniformMatrix4fv(uniformLocationIndex, 1, GL_TRUE, &orthMat[0][0]);
glViewport(0,0,w,h);
}
```

That uniformLocationIndex points to "projMat" in my vertex shader.

```
#version 330
in vec2 position;
in mat4 projMat;
void main() { 
    //vec4 contains normalized x and y coordinates
    gl_Position =  projMat * vec4(((-1.0) + position.x*(2.0/(2.0/projMat[0][0]))),
                                     (1.0 - position.y*(2.0/(-2.0/projMat[1][1]))),
                                     0.0, 1.0);

}
```

No matter where I put the points, they all go to the center and won't scale correctly when I resize the window. It is supposed keep the aspect ratio and scale down.

Comment: I assume your ortho matrix is calculated as prescribed at https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glFrustum.xml. If so why the complication in calculating gl_Position? Why not just gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);?

Comment: You might also want to calculate a view matrix as specified at https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml.  Then in your shader: gl_Position = projMat * viewMat  * vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);

Comment: Edit to my first comment: Why not just gl_Position = projMat * vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);?

Comment: @jwlaughton The orthMat is supposed to translate and scale all the points in the window when the window is resized. The x and y in the vec4 are being normalized to be between values 1 and -1. 2 / projMat[0][0] will give me the current width of the window.

Comment: I should add that all points work fine when just normalizing the points without applying the orthographic matrix (the points are in their right places), but when resizing the window, the points are stretched instead of translated and scaled. But when the normalized points are multiplied by the orthographic matrix, all the points go into the middle making the image look like a single dot.

Comment: I'll post this as an answer because it's a little long.

Comment: If what I suggested in my answer still doesn't work for you check that GL_TRUE is really what you want in your call to glUniformMatrix4fv.  You may want GL_FALSE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some math, and I think the problem is your shader calculation.

I created a projection Matrix with:

Left clipping plane = -1
Right clipping plane = 1
Top clipping plane = 1
Bottom clipping plane = -1
Near clipping plane = 0.001
Far clipping plane = 2

Comparing this matrix I created to yours, there are significant differences in rows 2 and 3, but since it looks like you don't use these, I ignored that.

I then did the math involved in your gl_Position calculation, and unless I got it wrong, I got:

Point (1, 1) transforms to (0, 0)
Point (1, -1) transforms to (0, 2) (outside the field of view)
Point (-1, 1) transforms to (-2, 0) (outside the field of view)
Point (-1, -1) transforms to (-2, 2) (outside the field of view)

I think you don't have rows 2 and 3 right in your matrix (0 and 1 look OK), but again since you don't use them you should be able to get by if in your shader you say something like:

```
vec4 Position = projMat * vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);

gl_Position = vec4(Position.x, Position.y, 0.0, 1.0);
```

Comment: What you said is right. The orthographic matrix normalizes the points, so normalizing again in the vec4 messed up the results. However, the problem persisted with the 2d float array. I copied the 2d float array into a 1d float array and it worked. I honestly have no idea why openGL didn't like my 2d float array, but nonetheless, the problem is solved. Thanks.

Comment: When you pass an 4X4 array (like projMat) to OpenGL, it actually gets passed as a 1D 16 element array.  You just need to be sure you tell OpenGL whether you're passing it in row major or column major format.  That's why I suggested in one of my comments that maybe your call to glUniformMatrix4fv should have said GL_FALSE instead of GL_TRUE.